# How to implement insertion linked list sort - sort by age

Tags: c++, linked-list

How would I implement a sort insertion here, I've been trying for a while to no success.

The 'isEmpty' method checks if the head == NULL, and insert at first method points the pointer to NULL after inserting the details entered by the user.

```
void insert(Person *&head, Person *&last, int age, string name, string surname, char gender)
{

    if(isEmpty(head))
        {
            insertAsFirst(head, last, age, name, surname, gender);
        }else
        {

        Person *temp = new Person;

         temp ->age = age;

         temp -> surname = surname;
         temp -> name = name;
         temp -> gender = gender;

         temp->next = NULL;
         last -> next = temp;
         last = temp;
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what do you want to achieve? I really don't get it

Comment: Hi sorry about that I really should of been more specific, I'm trying to implement an insertion sort to this list, sorting it by age. Each node consists of the following: A name, surname, gender and age.

Comment: @MichalTurek Unfortunately I haven't been able to implement the insertion sort because I'm quite new to linked lists.

Comment: Two things you can do to make your job easier when working with linked lists: 1: Observe [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Don't mix the linked list logic with the logic that uses the linked list. It's easier to solve, test, and debug two smaller problems than one big one. Taken the the logical conclusion, you can later replace the linked list with another container, an array-like class for example, that shares the same interface with little difficulty.

Comment: 2: Visualize the problem. Draw a lot of pictures. Draw the list before an operation. Draw what it needs to look like at each step. Draw what it looks like afterward. This will make it easier to spot mistakes like accidentally losing a link before you're done with it. It also gives you an excellent set of expectations you can compare with the program results while debugging.

Comment: In your case, ditch the else case in favour of a `find_position_for` function that returns where to insert an item in the list and an `insert_at` function that inserts the item in the list at that point. Now the link list doesn't even know it's being sorted. It just does basic linked list things like find and insert, and the user of the list doesn't care how the list does it. Both get to stay as simple as possible. And once you're done, you'll fins you don't need the if empty test. `find_position_for` would return the head position in an empty list and you just `insert_at` head without knowing

Comment: *"I've been trying for a while to no success."* -- surely you have something more advanced than simply inserting at the end after trying for a while? What have you tried, and which obstacles blocked your progress?

Comment: @JaMiT when trying to use the insertion sort method, to insert the node in the proper position. My code started displaying the age only, I got frustrated and deleted code back to the point where I could add in the variables (name, surname, age, gender), and display them without error.

Comment: @Vidur *"back to the point where I could add in the variables (name, surname, age, gender), and display them without error"* -- your code does not display anything. How did you know that the problem lay with your insertion routine instead of your display routine? When you make unjustified assumptions like that, you risk leaving vital clues out of your question. You had the ages displayed -- if they were in the desired order, you probably should have asked about the other data not being displayed. If they were not in order, you should have taken all data but age out of your [mre] and shown that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid creating an unsorted list in the first place: make sure any new node is immediately inserted in the *right* spot, keeping the list sorted.

Assuming all your other code is fine, you can do that as follows. Replace these lines:

```
 temp->next = NULL;
 last -> next = temp;
 last = temp;
```

...with this:

```
if (age <= head->age) {
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    return;
}
Person *curr = head;
// Find insertion point
while (curr->next != nullptr && age > curr->next->age) {
    curr = curr->next;
}
// Insert new node after curr
temp->next = curr->next;
curr->next = temp;
if (temp->next == NULL) {
    last = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This solved all the issues. I really appreciate it.